# TFLearn: Feeding batches from tfrecords file

Tags: tflearn

I have managed to create a .tfrecords file from a very large csv by using this post: https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/.  I would like to feed this in batches into a tflearn.DNN model.

Model example:

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 510])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1020)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1020)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)
```

To retrieve the data from the file:

```
def read_and_decode_single_example(filename):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],
                                                    num_epochs=None)

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([510], tf.float32)
        })

    _label = features['label']
    _features = features['features']
    return _label, _features
```

Is there a way to feed this file into the model.fit function?

```
labels, features = read_and_decode_single_example('data.tfrecords')
model.fit(features, labels)
```

The example shows that the labels and features should be initialised in a session first and to use this with TensorFlow, but I am not sure where to place this with TFLearn.

```
sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
```